# No overload for 'Button1_Click' matches delegate 'System.EventHandler'?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, gridviewrow, function-signature

I want to display values from db to grid view with image file. While using given below code it shows an error. Help me to find a proper solution.

Code:

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e1)
    {
        ShadingAnalysisDataSetTableAdapters.tbl_SiteLayOutUploadTableAdapter sl;
        sl = new ShadingAnalysisDataSetTableAdapters.tbl_SiteLayOutUploadTableAdapter();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt = sl.GetGridData(ddlSit.SelectedValue, int.Parse(ddlVersion.SelectedValue));
        try
        {
          if (e1.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow && gvEdit.EditIndex == e1.Row.RowIndex)
            {
              Image Image1 = (Image)e1.Row.FindControl("Image1");
              foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
               {
                  byte[] img1 = (byte[])row["ImgData"];
                  string base1 = Convert.ToBase64String(img1);
                  Image1.ImageUrl = "data:image/jpg;base64," + base1;
               }
          }
            gvEdit.DataSource = dt;
            gvEdit.DataBind();
        }
        catch (NullReferenceException ex)
        {

        }
    }
```

ASPX:

```
 <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
```

Comment: Is the button inside the gridview?

Comment: `Button_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)` - This is the default proto for click handler for a button (from MSDN). What you have given for a button click event handler is `GridViewRowEventArgs `. Should you just use `EventArgs`?

Comment: Don't ever ignore exceptions, except under very rare circumstances. And don't _ever_ ignore `NullReferenceException`.

Answer (score 3):

You need to change function prototype like below:

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e1)
 {
 }
```

Comment: That was my comment exactly @Rahul

Comment: @KarthikNishanth I was typing my answer same time

Comment: This won't solve the problem, there's `if (e1.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow` condition inside the method and it would produce another error.

Answer (score 1):

Parameters of your `Button1_Click` is wrong. It should look like below.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

Comment: This won't solve the problem, the code will break at `if (e1.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow` condition because you also change `e1` to `e`.